# Why does Chrome memory drop a massive amount when I manually collect garbage?

Tags: javascript, memory, garbage-collection

I am working on a javascript program that loads a file from the users computer and then extracts some information out of it, does other manipulation, and then loads certain aspects of those pieces for their viewing. I'm confident in the scope of my variables but for some reason Chrome, as well as other browsers, have significant memory retention for what appears to be no reason. Furthermore, it's impossible for me to see what is causing the retention because whenever you take a heap snapshot it automatically called a MajorGC when you stop it. If you leave the program as is then you get this usage:

[image: Memory Usage Prior]

and after manually calling the GC:
[image: Memory Usage After Manual GC]

My question is: what causes this retention and if it's cleared up with manual GC call then why isn't it cleared up when the scope of the functions ends? What does manually calling the GC even do? How can I do whatever it does in order to clear the memory allocation?

The following is a brief code snippet to where I think the issues arrise:

```
function init() {
    const fileInput = document.getElementById( 'fileInput' );
    fileInput.addEventListener( 'change', onFileChange, false );
}

function onFileChange() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById( 'fileInput' );
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function() { ... };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer( file );
}
```

Is there any chance that the `onloadend` function is creating a reference between the stuff I do in the function and the `fileInput` DOM element? Do I need to close the file object when I'm done with it? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Why are you worried? What you're describing sounds like the normal behavior of generational collection. If an object survives a young generation collection (or perhaps a few if there are survivor spaces), it will not be collected until a full GC happens. Finishing the execution of a function doesn't trigger a full GC, so it won't collect those values.

Comment: That said, we'd need to see the code for `reader.onloadend  = function() { ... }` to fully rule out a leak.

Comment: I'm concerned because in loading larger file the usage can be several gigabytes and hog an unnecessary amount of the users RAM. Also doesn't the fact that manually invoking the GC clears the memory mean that there isn't a leak?

Comment: You can't be leaking memory in the traditional sense, but you could be holding on to some reference to something longer than you need to. This sometimes gets called a space leak.